# What is the best entropy-free random generator for C#?

Tags: c#, random

I am doing a project involving taking millions of random samples from a set as part of a heuristic to find the best path in traveling salesman's problem. 
I need a random generator whose "randomness" will not be exhausted after that many samples. 
It should also be fast, and as random as possible.
What is the best random generator to use in such a case? 
(I know, C# isn't the best language for Traveling Salesman's, but that's the requirement :)).

EDIT: In order to clarify what I mean, /dev/random in UNIX systems is an entropy-based generator. This is why you must move your mouse to generate an SSH-key: the random number generator it uses is based on user input to generate entropy. In short, I need a good random number generator which is seed-based, not entropy based. I don't know whether or not the Random class was seed- or entropy- based. Further, I wonder if other classes out there use a better method than the Random class (which I assume uses linear congruence).

Comment: Define "its randomness being exhausted".

Comment: Time to call Aperture Science

Comment: "its randomness" means its equal distribution from 0 to int.MaxValue . Often random generators depend on entropy obtained from keystrokes from the user, but if overtaxed, these random generators become keylogs, and the next number comes from a much smaller subset of [0,int.MaxValue] than the entire set. This is sub-optimal.

Comment: @djhashkin987: This is not randomness. I can generate a uniform distribution with a counter.

Comment: @Oli: I know this. I wanted to illustrate what happens to certain other random generators: They are still randomish (based on keystrokes), but their range of values drops drammatically after over-taxation.

Comment: If you don't need cryptographically random data, PRNG's should have a cycle length that's sufficient – I strongly doubt .NET's implementation would cycle after a few million samples.

Comment: @djhaskin987: Ok.  But it's still not clear what you're after.  I mean, using the standard `System.Random` generates you a uniform distribution that doesn't repeat for 2 billion samples, but is entirely deterministic (i.e. it's not at all random).  Is that sufficient?

Comment: @djhaskin987 Why don't you use a `white noise` generator. http://www.maxim-ic.com/app-notes/index.mvp/id/3469 :)

Comment: @L.B I wish I could ;) I heard in the ia64 architecture is an instruction that uses white noise from the chip to generate a random number, but I don't think any OS uses it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The standard `System.Random` class uses (signed) 32 bit integers for the seed and values, expect it to  loop after 2 billion samples or so.

Comment: It's difficult to know if this answers the question or not, because the question is not sufficiently well-formed to be answerable.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth - the questions mentions "millions of samples" , which is (just) enough of to start fencing it in.

Comment: @Henk: I'm not sure what he means by "exhausted".  If he means "starts repeating", then yes, this answer is correct.  But he keeps mentioning keyloggers and entropy, which is something different.

Comment: /dev/random in UNIX systems is an entropy-based generator. This is why you must move your mouse to generate an SSH-key: the random number generator it uses is based on user input to generate entropy. In short, I need a good random number generator which is seed-based, not entropy based. I didn't know whether or not the `Random` class was seed- or entropy- based. This answer is particularly useful for that.

Comment: I just checked the implementation using Reflector. Microsoft uses a int[56] as seed value. So it can be expected that the random numbers will never start repeating in practice.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes you are **most probably** right, but having a large seed value doesn't mean anything at all. An alg. may start to repeat itself in a much shorter sequence.

Comment: It's the fastest, and it it meets our needs. I was thinking of mersene twister or mulitply by carry, but I'm glad to know System.Random does the job. Thanks!

Comment: System.Random is broken by Microsoft's own admission. Don't use it. Also, seed size doesn't mean anything. You can seed Mersene Twister with a 32 bit seed and the period will still be vastly larger than 2^32 simply because the state size is much larger than 2^32.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `System.Security.Cryptography.RandomNumberGenerator` to get a random number block for strong cryptography.  That should be sufficient randomness for your purposes.

Additional documentation can be found at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.randomnumbergenerator.aspx

After a quick benchmark I found I was able to generate 4 million bytes of random data in 28ms, and 400 million in just over 2.5 seconds.  This produced a byte array that could be hooked up to a `BinaryReader` to get any basic data type you need.

Comment: It's difficult to know if this answers the question or not, because the question is not sufficiently well-formed to be answerable.

Comment: @Henk True, I'll throw together a quick test to see what kind of performance I can get from it. I've never actually tried to use it before.

Comment: I was able to generate 4 million bytes of random data in 28ms, and 400 million bytes in about 2.5 seconds.

Comment: I don't think cryptographic randomness is needed for this problem pseudo random would be fine the problem requires statistically random data i don't think it matters if it is predictable.

Comment: @Ben Agreed, but he was talking a lot about entropy and I wanted to make sure that he was aware of the strong crypto random number generators that take this in to account.

Comment: Do not EVER use these generators in that way. They're based on the OS's cryptographic RNG which is entropy pool based. Drawing too many numbers from it can deplete the pools and cause potential security issues. Only ever use these generators to seed other generators.